# What is the proper way to position a CSS hover menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I put together a fiddle with a very basic hover example.

http://jsfiddle.net/qhj2P/

Here is the CSS:

```
.button
{
    width: 50px;
    height: 15px;
    background-color: #090;
    padding: 5px;
}

.menu
{
    height: 200px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: #900;
    display: none;    
}
```

I'm curious what the best way to position the menus is. How do I make it so that the first menu drops down right below the first button and the second menu drops down right below the second button? I'm not so good at CSS positioning and the like.

Comment: Build your menus as nested lists. It's more adequate semantically, and a starting point to fix the positioning problem.

Comment: Take a look at any of the trillion pre-made dropdown menus. See how their structure looks? Try replicating it and then try making it animate.

Comment: @Blender I am actively doing that, but stackers have a knack for very simple examples that always turn light bulbs on for me so I thought I'd see if anyone had a simple answer in the meantime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be to use `<ul>` instead of your current setup.
http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/fHmvs/1/

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="#">One</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Two</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
.menu li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
.menu ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    background: red;
}
.menu ul li { clear: both; }
.menu a {
    display: block;
    padding: .5em;
    margin: .1em;
}
```

jq:

```
$('.menu li').hover(function() {
    $(this).children('ul').stop(1, 1).slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a styled, unordered lists, not DIVs. Stick most of the styling on the A-tag with `display:block`.

```
<div class="menu">
<ul>
    <li><a href="...">Menu Item</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="...">Sub Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="...">Sub Item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="...">Menu Item</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.menu ul, .menu li {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style-type:none
}

.menu li {
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
}

.menu a {
    font-family:arial;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
    background-color:#c0c0c0;
    padding:3px;
    color:#000000
}

/* level two */

ul ul {
    position:absolute;
    display:none;    
}

ul ul a {
     background-color:#d0d0d0;
     margin-top:3px;   
}
```